# Using multiple lexer commands on one lexer rule in Antlr

Tags: antlr, lexer, mode

I'm trying to use more than one lexer command on a lexer rule.
My code looks something like that:

```
LEXER_RULE: something->mode(NUMBER);

mode NUMBER;
NU: [0-9]+ ->mode(ANOTHER_MODE); //Going into another mode in case the NU rule is used

//now leaving the NUMBER mode, in case there is no number written

NO_NUM: ~[0-9]->mode(DEFAULT_MODE);
```

The lexer rule NU is only optional, so I have to cover the case that it is not used. However, I would also like to skip everything that is inside NO_NUM.
Something like

`NO_NUM:~[0-9]->skip ->mode(DEFAULT_MODE);`

I know that I am not allowed to use more than one lexer command on one lexer rule. Does anyone know any other approach? I need to be able to leave the mode somehow. Btw I am not allowed to use semantic predicates. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there! Use a comma insetad:

```
NO_NUM : ~[0-9] -> skip, mode(DEFAULT_MODE);
```

This, obviously, discards anything that `~[0-9]` matches. So, if you have this grammar:

```
ID : [a-zA-Z]+;
...

mode NUMBER;
  NU.    : [0-9]+ -> mode(ANOTHER_MODE);
  NO_NUM : ~[0-9] -> skip, mode(DEFAULT_MODE);

mode ANOTHER_MODE;
  ...
```

And in `mode NUMBER` you encounter `abc`, then `a` is discarded, and `bc` will be made into an `ID`. If you also want the `a` to be part of the `ID`, then you need to do this:

```
ID : [a-zA-Z]+;
...

mode NUMBER;
  NU.    : [0-9]+ -> mode(ANOTHER_MODE);
  NO_NUM : ~[0-9] -> more, mode(DEFAULT_MODE);

mode ANOTHER_MODE;
  ...
```

More about Lexer Command: https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/lexer-rules.md#lexer-commands

Comment: You even solved the problem I encountered as a consequence of skipping the first sign. Thank you so much!